# Can we append dynamically background-images to dynamic classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I am working on a list/content carousel i had a problem in that i need to append the images to certain classes dynamically using handlebars is that possible?

Comment: can your share any links for me to refer.

Comment: Show us your code - explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: @user2959178 I think what they really want is some code to look and and then they can advise.  Basically "what have you tried"?

Comment: sorry i don't have code to show. but i want to know can we do it or not. anyway thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

You can register custom helperfunctions which you can use to render templates.

You find everything you need [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)

I Hope this helps :-)

Comment: how can we append background images to css class dyanmically

Comment: you could extend the stylesheet in the helperfunction so a certain class has a passed background-image

Comment: You could also add an background-image in your style-attribute (in your template) if you dont want to affect a whole css-class. There are a couple of ways to accomplish that. I hope this helps you a bit.